# Unable to handle the cancel VOIP push comes after rejecting the incoming call push

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, callkit

I have already developed a VOIP call app that uses pushkit for VOIP push notification. Our notification server is designed to deliver all cancel notifications along with new incoming call notifications through VOIP push (This behavior can't be changed as of now). Since it has become mandatory to report all incoming push notifications to callkit after the iOS 13 release. There are scenarios where I am not able to report the cancel PUSH notification to callkit which ultimately result in app crash

Scenario:

If the user rejects the incoming call PUSH notification (i.e. basically rejecting the incoming call), the notification server delivers a cancel PUSH notification just after that. But since the new incoming call has already been rejected and there is no active callId to report, there is no way to report the cancel PUSH notification to callkit.  So, failure to report the cancel push results in in-app crash. This does happen in all those where there is no active/pending call and the client the PUSH for cancel notification.

Please help me out with how to handle this scenario.

Comment: The obvious answer is to send a normal notification instead of a VoIP one. But since you write that this can't be done, maybe in that specific scenario you can temporary un-register the VoIP push device token, so that the Cancel notification will not be received

Comment: @ArikSegal Thanks for the response! But not sure if unregister the VOIP push will make sense here since both events receiving incoming cancel push for reject call and unregister VOIP calls are independent of each other and asynchronous as well. Moreover, it will overhead for the app to unregister for each cancel which it expects while no active/pending call, and then register back.

Answer (score 2):

As you've said: starting from iOS 13 it has become mandatory to report a new incoming call for every VoIP push received.

There's no way around that. If you can't change the behavior of your server, the only thing you can do to avoid a crash (and the blocking of subsequent VoIP pushes delivery) is to report a fake call to make PushKit happy and immediately terminate it.

```
let callId = UUID()
cxProvider.reportNewIncomingCall(
    with: callId,
    update: callUpdate,
    completion: { [weak self] error in
        completion()
        self?.cxProvider.reportCall(with: callId, endedAt: nil, reason: .failed)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Marco! We are doing it currently but this does cause the incoming call UI to come up every time a cancel notification arrive. Is there a way we can avoid the incoming call UI to appear itself ?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't. The only way to flawlessly solve the problem is to avoid to send the cancel notification in the first place, but you said that you can't change the server behavior. So, this is the best you can get, sorry.

Comment: It takes around 1 second to show the fake call then auto end as you report end, it's not a really good UX. Is there any other ways to handle @Marco?

Comment: @jacob Of course it's not a good UX, it's really annoying, I know. But, as I've already said: it's a workaround to make iOS happy if and only if you can't avoid sending VoIP pushes that are not signaling a new incoming call while there isn't an active call. If your server only sends VoIP pushes for new incoming calls (that is what Apple wants you to do), you don't need this workaround.

Comment: @Marco Sounds like silent push for call cancel is the best choice. One more question, as i see, this issue seems to happen for inactive state, is it right? (Since i check the crashlytics logs and all is in background)

Comment: @jacob No, you can't use background/silent pushes in this case: "the system doesn’t guarantee their delivery" (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app). And yes (almost), it only happens when the app is inactive and there isn't an ongoing CallKit call (see this answer and also my comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62299986/1082528).

Comment: Thanks @Marco
I have tried, the use-case is: i report a fake call and immediately end like your solution, an end call screen appear, then i tap to answer -> display the callback screen -> tap to callback -> my app is launched and crash with the same crash log. Do you have any experience on this? Thanks

Comment: @jacob It's not clear to me what you're doing. I think that a simple comment it's not the right tool. I suggest you to write a proper question where you can better explain all the details of your issue.

Comment: Thank you @Marco, i found my problem and solved.

Comment: @jacob Can you please share the link or solution you have found.I m mostly looking for the same solution but not getting what exactly can be done.

What i want to achieve is that once i place the call and end it so on another end how do i dismiss the UI of call kit which is already initialised ?

For eg. 
If i have placed the call by mistake and want to dismiss call kit UI.

Comment: @SULEMANBAWA Just create a fake call the immediately terminate it. This is the most suitable solution.